# No more `private init` in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

I saw a number of references to using `private init` in Swift to restrict object construction (e.g. [this](http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton)), yet it does not seem to be possible when I try (in Xcode 7.2.1 Playground):

```
class C {
    private init() {}
}

var c = C() // No errors.
```

Am I missing something or is this actually a bug?

Comment: Not sure, but I believe if your class is subclassed from `NSObject` then it could **nullify** the `private` init and allow more instantiations.

Comment: No, it's just "private to file scope" in Swift 2. In Swift 3 there are two different access levels: now true `private` and this old `fileprivate`.

Comment: That I know. I was pointing out to that as *another* reason

Comment: Unfortunately, it has no relation to the example code in the question. You can check you presumption in a playground in a couple of minutes though :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're probably expecting `private` to restrict the use to within the class definition, but that's not what it does.

The definition of `private` is to "restrict the use of an entity to its own defining source file".

From the Swift book, ["Access Control"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) chapter.

EDIT:

As of Swift 3 `fileprivate` does what `private` used to and `private` is now more restrictive in that it "restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration"

Comment: Absolutely correct (I have just found the answer as well). Thanks for your effort.

Comment: It seems this has been changed for Swift 3.0. The language now has the term `fileprivate` to mean "restricted to source file", and `private` now means "restricted to enclosing definition" as it should.

Comment: @MikePollard, what TheSoundDefense said is true... You may want to edit your answer.